# 0x cc vs 0x cd 03 (int 3)

Tags: debugging, x86

Debuggers generate int3 instruction at the breakpoint so that the control goes to debug exception handler. For int3 debuggers will insert 0x cc. Why don't they insert 0x cd 03 which also means int3? What will happen if they insert 0x cd 03 instead of 0x cc?

Comment: Well, there are documented differences between the two in Intel’s Software Developer Manuals (please browse them), but a very obvious difference is that a 1-byte breakpoint can be placed anywhere; A 2-byte breakpoint is much harder to place, especially over a 1-byte instruction.

Comment: Can you give an example where 2-byte instruction is harder to place than 1-byte instruction? I don't find any except in some cases where the instruction is located at the end of the page.

Comment: If you squash a [1-byte instruction](http://xxeo.com/single-byte-or-small-x86-opcodes) with a 2-byte one, you corrupt the _next_ instruction. 1) If that instruction was the target of a branch/jump/call, you can totally break the code or transform it into a different (sequence of) instruction(s) entirely. 2) If there should be a breakpoint on the next instruction as well, it’s impossible. 3) As you noted, there may not be space to put it. 1-byte instructions have the guarantee of fitting anywhere without collateral damage.

Comment: I am not sure about this but usually, debuggers will replace the code with the old code right?

For ex: push eax ;mov 0x0, %eax. If we set a breakpoint at push, even though if it places cd 03 at that push instruction, before transferring the control to the original program, debugger will usually change the 2 instructions with those of mov right?

Comment: And look at this case also: Debuggers usually won't insert int3 in the beginning right? Because, if we have push eax; mov 0x0,%eax, if we put 2 breakpoints initially at push and mov, only 0x cc will work 0x cd 03 will fail (As it is going to overwrite the first cd 03). Otherwise, both will work fine right? And I want to know when will the debugger insert the int3 instruction?

Comment: _Only if the processor first hits the first byte of the instruction!_ If a jump targets the _next_ instruction after a single-byte one, and you put a 2-byte breakpoint, and your code jumps to what used to be something else but is now the `03` of `cd 03`, then it _*won’t*_ be interpreted as a breakpoint but a different instruction entirely!

Comment: Debuggers never ever put `cd 03` instead of `cc`. It’s strictly worse/more complicated.

Comment: I understood now, which means debuggers will insert the int 3 instruction as soon as we put a breakpoint right? But how to verify when will debuggers insert the int 3 instruction? because if we examine the memory contents of instructions with debuggers, they will show original instruction instead of int3.

Comment: Debuggers will always place a 1-byte `int3` instruction over the _first_ (and possibly only) byte of the instruction, while reading the byte that was there before and saving it in the breakpoints list. Because debuggers know which breakpoints they’ve made and where, and their job is to interfere as little as possible with the program state (unless you tell it otherwise), they will “lie” to you about the memory contents. Usually that’s done by switching out all the breakpoints after one is hit, and switching them back in right before continuing the program.

Comment: @Iwill, your first comment would make a good answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intel's documentation for that instruction answers your question for you:  the Description section in the vol.2 manual entry for [`int` / `int3`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/intn:into:int3:int1) says:

> The INT3 instruction uses a one-byte opcode (CC) and is intended for calling the debug exception handler with a breakpoint exception (#BP). (This one-byte form is useful because it can replace the first byte of any instruction at which a breakpoint is desired, including other one-byte instructions, **without overwriting other instructions**.)

There are some 1-byte x86 instructions like `push reg`.  Or in 16/32-bit mode `inc/dec reg`.  **If a 1-byte instruction was the last instruction before a branch target**, overwriting it with a longer instruction would corrupt the first byte of an instruction that can run without reaching the breakpoint.

---

**There are other differences for vm86 mode** between the two byte `cd 03` encoding of `int 3` vs the 1-byte `int3` encoding, again documented right in the manual.  (Presumably to make it easier to write debuggers that debug the vm86 guest from outside the vm86 environment.)

> An interrupt generated by the `INTO`, `INT3`, or `INT1` instruction differs from one generated by `INT n` in the following ways:
>
> - The normal IOPL checks do not occur in virtual-8086 mode. The interrupt is taken (without fault) with any IOPL value.
> - The interrupt redirection enabled by the virtual-8086 mode extensions (VME) does not occur. The interrupt is always handled by a protected-mode handler.
>
> (These features do not pertain to `CD03`, the “normal” 2-byte opcode for INT 3. Intel and Microsoft assemblers will not generate the `CD03` opcode from any mnemonic, but this opcode can be created by direct numeric code definition or by self-modifying code.)

BTW, in NASM/YASM, you *do* need to use the `int3` mnemonic for the 1 byte encoding; `int 3` does assemble to `CD 03`

GAS assembles `int $3` the same as `int3`, to `0xcc`

But of course debuggers are working with binary machine code, not asm source.  The assembly-mnemonic stuff only applies to manually including a breakpoint in your asm source.  (Yes, that's a thing you can do.  Most debuggers will let you resume by skipping over that instruction.)